# Ruby MongoClient: Initializing from irb succeeds, initializing from script fails

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm trying to initialize a MongoClient from a script but I am failing.
What I simply do is:

```
require 'mongo'
include Mongo
client = MongoClient.new("localhost", 27017)
```

and it fails with the following error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.9.1/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:43:in `initialize': undefined method `connection' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.9.1/lib/mongo/db.rb:564:in `new'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.9.1/lib/mongo/db.rb:564:in `command'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.9.1/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:591:in `block in check_is_master'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in `timeout'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.9.1/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:590:in `check_is_master'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.9.1/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:474:in `connect'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.9.1/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:698:in `setup'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.9.1/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:155:in `initialize'
    from ./test.rb:52:in `new'
    from ./test.rb:52:in `<main>'
```

But, when I try the exact same thing from irb, it works.

Ruby version is:

> ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

irb is:

> /usr/bin/irb1.9.1 --version
>   irb 0.9.6(09/06/30)

I also tried requiring 'rubygems', but from what i know, Ruby 1.9 doesn't need it.
Am I forgetting something?

Comment: This works just fine for me as described; can you provide a minimum complete failing example?

Comment: Chris, that is a minimum complete failing example. That's all that is in the file...and yet it works in irb...

Comment: It definitely works here; the error is being thrown because there's no active connection object, but it should bomb out before then. Consider opening a bug report on the Mongo Ruby driver.

Comment: Yeah, I think I will. I'm also gonna try installing a different Ruby version, just in case. Thanks.

Comment: This would break a lot of people if it wasn't working correctly. My suspicion is that this may be an environment issue on your end. What version of the mongo gem are you using? Why does your irb appear to be under a different ruby runtime (1.9.1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by re-installing ruby. I never found out what the problem was and what was causing it.

Thanks for everyone's help.